# Add concatenated column to temp table when I don't have ADD permission

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, temp-tables

I do not have ADD or DELETE or ALTER permission in my instance of SQL Server.  I have a temp table in which I want to add a column to.

This new column is a concatenation of other columns and I want to write it to another temp table.

Right now, when I employ the CONCAT code below, the output is just that one column.  I want to have the CONCAT column along with all the other columns in my original temp table (#df_ERA4_b).

```
SELECT CONCAT(A, OP, F, SUB, AIR, D, REQ, P) as CONCAT_COL
INTO #df_ERA4_c 
FROM #df_ERA4_b
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you create a view ?

Comment: what is a view and how do you create one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a * to include all other rows, or list them explicitly.

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CONCAT(A, OP, F, SUB, AIR, D, REQ, P) as CONCAT_COL
INTO #df_ERA4_c 
FROM #df_ERA4_b
```

Comment: I forgot the comma!